# Groovy URL getText() returns a PasswordAuthentication instance

Tags: authentication, jenkins, url, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to download the content of a password-protected Gerrit URL in a Jenkins pipeline Groovy script. HTTPBuilder is not accessible so I am using the URL class with Authenticator:

```
// To avoid pipline bailing out since data PasswordAuthentication is non-serializable
@NonCPS
def getToString(data) {
    data.toString()
}

def fetchCommit(host, project, version) {
    withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'my-credentials',
                                      usernameVariable: 'user',
                                      passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD')]) {
        proj = java.net.URLEncoder.encode(project, 'UTF-8')
        echo "Setting default authentication"
        Authenticator.default = {
            new PasswordAuthentication(env.user, env.PASSWORD as char[])
        } as Authenticator
        echo "https://${host}/a/projects/${proj}/commits/${version}"
        url = "https://${host}/a/projects/${proj}/commits/${version}".toURL()
        result = getToString(url.getText())
        echo "${result}"
    }
}
```

The result is a PasswordAuthentication instance, and not the expected data:

```
[Pipeline] echo
java.net.PasswordAuthentication@3938b0f1
```

I have been wrestling with this for a while. I have tried different ways to setup the authentication and reading the data, but those mostly end up with an exception. Using eachLine() on the url does not enter the closure at all. The job also exits far to quickly, giving the impression it not even tries to make a connection.

Refs:

- https://kousenit.org/2012/06/07/password-authentication-using-groovy/

Comment: why `HTTPBuilder is not accessible`?

Comment: The import statement fails, presumably it's not part of the jx installation: `unable to resolve class groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder`.

Comment: of course it fails. you should use `@Grab('io.github.http-builder-ng:http-builder-ng-CLIENT:1.0.4')` annotation in the beginning of your script

Comment: Ok, thanks. I tried but it is not possible due to CPS restrictions: `General error during conversion: Annotation Grab cannot be used in the sandbox`. Need to have the sandbox enabled.

Comment: I'm not an expert in Jenikins, but I think it's worth to configure standard groovy lib (as third-party) in Jenkins and have the problem solved for future, than each time resort to some custom hand-made hacks

Comment: Hm, not sure what you are getting at? I am unable to find a pipeline step for downloading the data from an URL without a node setting, and I don't see how using HTTPBuilder is less of a hack than using URL?